# Добавление записи в бд через DropDownList ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
 string InsertQuery = "";
        InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Form (Name, Email, Service_type) VALUES ('" + Name.Text + "','" + Email.Text + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(Type.SelectedValue) + "'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
        SqlCommand idlast = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, Connection);
        string last = idlast.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

вот код Service_type поле в которое нужно записать, Type собственно сам айдишник dropdownlist-а.
Что не так с моим кодом?

Выдает ошибку

> Входная строка имела неверный формат.

Comment: Опасно пишете. Вообще такую ошибку возвращает метод Convert, начните с проверки что вы туда передаете

Comment: @Андрей когда передаю елемент (вместо Selected Value) то его успешно записывает в базу без никаких ошибок

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(Type.SelectedValue)` этот метод вам возвращает ошибку. Разбирайтесь.